# Linq how parameters are passed in select

Tags: linq

I am learning LINQ and I found this example.

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 

var numsInPlace = numbers.Select((num, index) => new { Num = num, InPlace = (num == index) }); 

Console.WriteLine("Number: In-place?"); 
foreach (var n in numsInPlace) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", n.Num, n.InPlace); 
}
```

I don't understand execution of the below line:

```
var numsInPlace = numbers.Select((num, index) => new { Num = num, InPlace = (num == index) });
```

As per my understanding `num` and `index` are parameters, but I don't understand where we decide that first parameter will be a number and second parameter will be index of the number?

Is it something that is fixed for int type of arrays?

Can anybody please help me understanding this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq- Indexed Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853315/linq-indexed-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of method Select decides it.
There are at lest 2 definitions for Select and one says it takes `Func<MyInput,int,MyReturn>`.  We know that all but the last `generic parameter` of Func are inputs, and the last one is output.
Func is a special type of object (type of delegate) that has a method called Invoke() to run it and a special syntax-sugar - shorthand `()` which says that you can omit the `Invoke` and just write `()`.

```
Func<object, int> d = x => 1 
d.Invoke(null) // will always return 1
d(new Object()) // also the same
```

[image]

So compiler takes your function and tries to find one of Selects that can accept this kind of function. Then it compiles. And then in run-time the Select just takes first, second etc. element from collection and runs your function by passing the element (and the index if the overload of Select with the function that accepts index has been chosen).

Comment: How do you expand the overload list like that?

Comment: In this case i have a ReSharper. It is quite common tool. Sorry I can't even show you how it works in vs without Resharper. 
Hint: Ctrl + Spacebar helps a lot  by showing popups and info when text cursor in the right place.

Answer (score -1):

(num, index, TResult) => new { .... } is an anonymous function of type Func delegate.
It is defined by .Net Framework. Thus the First parameter is an object, where as second parameter is index of an object in an array.

```
Func<T, Index, TResult> Delegate
```

Func translated to English is: “A method that takes an T and Index of T in an array, and returns a TResult.

There is another thing called Action delegate, where there is no return.

Please have a reference to this link: 
http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/09/24/explaining-what-action-and-func-are/

Answer (score -1):

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx).

The first argument to selector represents the element to process. The second argument to selector represents the zero-based index of that element in the source sequence. This can be useful if the elements are in a known order and you want to do something with an element at a particular index, for example. It can also be useful if you want to retrieve the index of one or more elements.